# PHP directory problems

Tags: php, directory

I got a problem with this:

I got file xxx.php in which I'm parsing one file: $config['etc'] = parse_ini_file('config/config.txt');

Everything is fine, until I'm including xxx.php file to my yyy.php file using `require_once("lang.inc.php");`

Then I get an message: Warning: parse_ini_file(config/config.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in ...

When I change ;

$config['etc'] = parse_ini_file('config/config.txt');

to

$config['etc'] = parse_ini_file('../config/config.txt');

then my yyy.php works fine, but xxx.php not... and I'm in stuck.

Help me guys, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using absolute file paths if your PHP scripts can be invoked (or requested) from different directories. For example, the current directory of a PHP script executed under `example.com/one.php` will be different from `example.com/folder/two.php`.

Your change to

```
$config['etc'] = parse_ini_file('../config/config.txt');
```

is still *relative*, except this time it's just "one directory up from the current directory > config > config.txt", rather than before, where you were looking in the same current directory.

A generic fix would be to do the following:

```
$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
// ... code ...
$config['etc'] = parse_ini_file($root . '/config/config.txt');
```

There are possible issues with using the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` field, but it should be fine for the most part (such as `DOCUMENT_ROOT` not being defined under the CLI). Also, check if `DOCUMENT_ROOT` has a trailing slash, even though the standard is not to have it, some hosts may have the trailing slash included. If it does, remove your slash at the beginning of your file path.

Comment: parse_ini_file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/config/config.txt');
...and it worked but *__FILE__* throws up an error message.

Comment: when I use *__FILE__* instead of $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] it throws up this error msg: (net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED)

Comment: `__FILE__` specifies the current file. For example, replacing `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` with `__FILE__` would result in `/home/freedompeace/public_html/dir1/index.php/config/config.txt` because of the string concatenation, which is obviously *not* what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should use absolute path or path from `yyy.php` to `config.txt`
TO get absolute one you can use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` or `__FILE__` constant

Comment: But I'm parsing config.txt with xxx.php file, not yyy, in yyy.php I'm just including the xxx.php :S.

Comment: I know, but when you include xxx.php in yyy.php code works as added in yyy.php

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because your file hierarchy looks like this?

```
/
- file/
-- config/
---config.txt
--- yyy.php
- xxx.php
```

xxx.php and yyy.php is not in the same directory. When you include xxx.php in yyy.php, the `parse_ini_file` will read the file **from the yyy.php perspective**. That's why you need to change the directory, because when you include a file, all of its direcotry reading changed.

The solution is of course has been written by others (use absolute path), or you can just move the files to the same direcotry. I'm just writes this for the full explanation.

**EDIT:**

Of course, I'm just speculating your file hierarchy. Just try to imagine the file hierarchy, and see if xxx.php and yyy.php is not in the same directory. That might be the problem.

**EDIT 2:**
I've tried the situation you write in the question, and it works without problem. This is the code I made:

***`xxx.php:`***

```
<?php
    $config = parse_ini_file('config/config.txt');
```

***`yyy.php:`***

```
<?php
    require_once "xxx.php";
```

The file hierarchy:

```
/
- config/
-- config.txt
- xxx.php
- yyy.php
```

Works just fine. Maybe your yyy.php is included on another file, and called from that file?

Comment: Hm, xxx.php and yyy.php are in one file .

Comment: I don't understand. Why would you need to include it if it's in one file? Do you mean one directory?

Comment: If it's on the same directory, it should works. I just tried to create the files you said, and don't get any error. Have you tried the absolute path soulution?

Comment: Yea, I've already tried path like: /home/public_html/config/config.txt , but it looks kinda strange :p

Comment: @Lucas let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2184/discussion-between-bertzzie-and-lucas)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
class Database extends PDO{ public $koneksi;   function
__construct($file = './../db/config.ini'){
    try{

   if (!$settings = parse_ini_file(__DIR__.$file, TRUE)) throw new
exception('Unable to open ' . $file . '.');
        $driver=$settings['database']['driver'];
        $dsn=$settings['database']['dsn'];
        $port=$settings['database']['port'];
        $dbname=$settings['database']['dbname'];        $username=$settings['database']['username'];
   $password=$settings['database']['password'];

        $this->koneksi = new PDO("mysql:host=" .$dsn . ";dbname=" . $dbname, $username,$password,array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE =>
PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES
utf8"));
        $this->koneksi->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    }catch(PDOException $e){
        $e->getMessage();
    }   
}
```