# php Warning: parse_ini_file, failed to open stream: No such file or directory in

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I created an config.ini file with db credentials and parsing that file in my dbconnect.php page like this way -

```
$config = parse_ini_file('../somefolder/config.ini'); 
$connection = mysqli_connect($config['servername'],$config['username'],$config['password'],$config['dbname']);
```

it is connecting the database and returns data in my first page. But when I go to another page which calls the same dbconnect.php, it shows the error

> Warning: parse_ini_file('../somefolder/config.ini'): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in E:\wamp64\www\sample\dbconnect.php on line 12

Any help appreciated, thank you

Comment: does `\www\sample\dbconnect.php` match the location of your `dbconnect.php` file in your project hierarchy? & is the 'another page' file in the same directory as the first file?

Comment: Try `parse_ini_file(__DIR__ . '/../somefolder/config.ini')`

Comment: thank you, yes it matches the location of dbconnect.php, otherwise it shouldn't connect the first page.

Answer (score 0):

The path to parse_ini_file() has to change if the script you included it in is housed in a directory separate from the first file. Just adding (or removing) two dots and a forward slash could solve your problem. Besides, showing us your file structure would go a long way. This link could also help: 
[PHP directory problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965402/php-directory-problems)

Comment: Thank you mr. @Benny64 for the comment. I solved the issue by changing the destination of the .ini file. I just moved the file in to a different directory and it works fine.